# in javascript, argument order of evaluation and delayed evaluation

Tags: javascript

1. if `function( arg1, arg2 )`, am I correct in believing `arg1` is guaranteed to evaluated before `arg2` (unlike classic C for example)?
2. is there any way to have a function where the arguments are not evaluated, but rather evaluated on demand?  for example, `if( cond1 || cond2 )` evaluates `cond2` if and only if `cond1` is false.  is it possible to write our own `if`-like function?

for example, could I write a function like oracle's `nvl( arg1, arg2, ... )`, which returns the first non-null argument, evaluating them lazily.  in a regular function call, all arguments are evaluated before the function body is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function arguments are evaluated before they're passed to the function, so what you're asking for isn't technically possible. However, you could do this:

```
function nvl() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var res = arguments[i]();
        if (res)
            return res;
    }
}

nvl(function() { return false; }, 
    function() { return 7; }, 
    function() { return true; });
```

The call to `nvl` returns `7`.

All of the function wrappers are created, but only the bodies of the first two are evaluated inside `nvl`.

This isn't exactly pretty, but it would allow you to prevent an expensive operation in the body of any of the functions after the first one returning a truthy value.

Comment: you're a sick puppy and I commend you.  (although for your example nvl() false would be returned since it's not null.)  would you need to so something about scoping as well so the functions would be called in the same scope?

Comment: This is utterly pointless (no offense).  The code `false || 7 || true` has identical functionality as I was trying to point out.

@cc young - no it wouldn't.  `if(res)` isn't a null check, it's a falsy check.

Comment: I know your code did what you said and I thought I showed my appreciation - all I was trying to do is say that isn't how the original oracle nvl() works - which is not a reflection on your code at all

Comment: @cwolves - If you take "identical" to mean "sort of the same", then, yes. This is done in a function, which is what the OP is looking for. Your example is very good and relevant, but it cannot be done in a function, because the arguments will still be evaluated first.

Comment: the OP doesn't know what he's asking for.  He's asking for functionality from another language because it's what he's used to.  If you wanted this in a function call, it's simply `fn(false || 7 || true)`, but that's not what the OP wanted, he wanted a function like NVL, which is what you wrote, but that function is useless because it can 100% be replaced by `false || 7 || true`.  Using the OR operator IS the correct way to do this in JavaScript; copying another language's way of doing it is not.

Answer (score 1):

in your first example, yes, if you're calling a function they will be evaluated in order.

In the 2nd example, JS does not evaluate every param (just like C), e.g.:

```
if(true || x++){
```

x++ will never run.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: good example ... shows nicely how conditions are lazily evaluated in javascript.

Comment: right!  would like to write a function like oracle's <code>nvl()</code>, which returns the first non-null argument.  like <code>if</code>, arguments need to be lazily evaluated.

Comment: there's no point to that.  The `||` operator accomplishes the same thing: `cond1 || cond2() || cond3()`, etc.  It will only evaluate until a non-false.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Yes, with `if(cond1 || cond2)`, cond2 will be evaluated iff cond1 is false.

Here is a function that return the first truthy argument:

```
function firstDefinedArgument(){
    for(var i in arguments){
        if(arguments[i]){
           return arguments[i];
        }
     }
 }
```

So, for example, `firstDefinedArgument(0, null, undefined, "", "hello", "goodbye")` would return `"hello"`.

If you wanted to return the first non-null argument instead of the first truthy one, you would replace `if(arguments[i])` with `if(arguments[i] !== null)`. This function would return `0` in the above example.

Comment: right, but would like to write a function that behaves similarly

Comment: @cc young 
I made a function like that. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: No. The arguments are still evaluated before they're passed. What the OP wants is not possible, basically, although I have an idea.